# Poisson Distribution Probability (Percentage with mean value)

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

At a candy store, customers arrive randomly with mean value E=20 per hour.
10% of customers buy lollipops. What's the distribution of costumers buying lollipops per hour?

We know that X~Pois(20). X Being the random-var counting time between two events = time between the arrival of two customers.
I thought of simply that since 10% of customers buy lollipops, then 10% per-hour must do too. Hence 10% * 20 per hour = 2 per hour buy lollipops.

 Is that right? Or am I doing something totally unrelated?

Comment: Looks good to me.